# Babel unexpected token with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Whenever I use a circumflex(^) inside of my regex babel won't compile. An example of my regular expression:

```
lastPage.replace(/https?://[^/]+/g, '');
```

What is going wrong here? My code editor also seems to be throwing up a red flag for the circumflex. Do I need to escape it or something?

In my terminal when using watch with Webpack:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token (190:56)

Which points to my ^ character.

Comment: escape the slashes.

Comment: Tried that as well like this: `.replace(/https?:\/\/[^/]+/, '');` but that does not matter.

Comment: all the slashes.

Comment: @Stephan-v You missed one. Inside of the square brackets.

Comment: Actually my above example seems to work but this does not work with the babel compiler: `.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/g, '');` At least it works, I have no idea why but it does.

Comment: @Stephan-v [It does work](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=OTB0CcFMAcBsEMDGkAUB6AFgFy9AzgPwBcAOmmQNoB6ZAugNRoDmANAAQgCUA3EA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0) unless you're running some weird extra syntax plugins.

Comment: @Stephan-v [Further proof that it works just fine.](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUByAFgF2wBwgC4B6YgI2gENN5QBbY7TASzGXXgCdY8rhZUxHPggB-QgB1iUgNoA9YgF0A1MWQAaAATp0ASl0BuIA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0) Open your console to see the output.

Comment: Don't worry I believe it works with babel, I guess something else is going on. Thanks for helping me out though.

Comment: @Stephan-v Sure thing. If you get another lead on the problem I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `/` within regex otherwise which denotes the ending of a regex pattern. After the ending slash only [regex flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) can be placed.

```
lastPage.replace(/https?:\/\/[^/]+/g, '');

// or
lastPage.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/g, '');
```

**FYI :** Within the character(or negated character) class, there is no need to escape `/`.

Comment: This question is just a simple syntax error/typo and should be closed as such.

Comment: Actually it does not compile with `[^\/]` it does compile with `[^/]` and the rest of the regex escaped. So this is not simply a syntax issue.

Comment: @Stephan-v I've already proven to you that it does work though. There's either something else in your code causing the error or you have some kind of weird experimental plugin.